# Java Database and ArrayList is passing the wrong values through iterator

Tags: java, database, jdbc, arraylist

I am in a bit of a trouble here. Basically I am trying to pass into my database some integer numbers. If the array list lets say contains 30 numbers, the database will filled indeed with 30 integers, but the problem is, that the integers stored there, are totally wrong. Suppose that my array list got this numbers [1 2 3 4 5], my database stores values like [0 20 3 5 6].

```
try
{
    for (int j : numbersList) 
    {

        String message="INSERT INTO numbers (number) VALUES ('" + numbersList.get(j) + "')";

        System.out.println("Query executed : " + message);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
        stat.executeUpdate(message);
        conn.commit();

    }

    System.out.println(numbersList);

} 
catch (SQLException ex) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Beyond the fact that you should always use parameterized statements and never paste string together, does `numbersList` contain the actual values you want to insert? If so, then why are you treating `j` like an index back into the list?

Comment: @chrylis damn yeah, I just didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String message="INSERT INTO numbers (number) VALUES ('" + j + "')";
```

Try this. You were using j as an index. So if the first element is 3 it will take the 4th element in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing with ForEach and normal for loop

if you are using - `for (int j : numbersList)`  - then you need to use `j` as Dinal explained.

Other wise - for traditional for loop `(int j=0;j<numbersList.size();j++)` - your code is fine - `numbersList.get(j)`

Comment: Thanks for input. In fact, it seems that I confused the traditional for loop with arraylist iterator. Thanks anyway, I am new to java ;)